# Webpack npm script cannot find command "src/index.js"

Tags: npm, webpack

I am having trouble with webpack, or at-least I assume it is with webpack.

I have installed it using npm. I have been following the Mithril.js Simple App tutorial which says to do the following in my package.json

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch"
  }
}
```

I ran the following command in the root of my project directory which contains a `src/` folder that has my `index.js` file. I also have a `bin/` folder which will hold the output from the webpack command specified in my `package.json` file shown above.

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli
```

So I proceed to run:

```
npm start
```

Below is the error that I get at runtime. Something about not being able to find `src/index.js` which is there and not misspelled, I checked more than once.

**Direct Terminal output:**

> ```
> user@ubunutu:~/Projects/mothersrfc/client$ ll
> total 60
> drwxrwxr-x  2 jreyes jreyes  4096 Jan  6 21:45 bin
> drwxrwxr-x 97 jreyes jreyes  4096 Jan  6 21:09 node_modules
> -rw-rw-r--  1 jreyes jreyes   382 Jan  6 22:23 package.json
> -rw-rw-r--  1 jreyes jreyes 42984 Jan  6 21:09 package-lock.json
> drwxrwxr-x  2 jreyes jreyes  4096 Jan  6 22:26 src
> user@ubunutu:~/Projects/mothersrfc/client$ npm start
> npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/3527/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
>
> > mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start /home/jreyes/Projects/mothersrfc/client
> > webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch
>
> [webpack-cli] Unknown command 'src/index.js'
> [webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start: `webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/jreyes/.npm/_logs/2021-01-07T05_00_13_372Z-debug.log
> user@ubunutu:~/Projects/mothersrfc/client$
> ```

and here is my error log from npm....

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [ '/snap/node/3527/bin/node', '/snap/node/3527/bin/npm', 'start' ]
> 2 info using npm@6.14.10
> 3 info using node@v14.15.4
> 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
> 5 info lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~prestart: mothersrfc-client@1.0.0
> 6 info lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: mothersrfc-client@1.0.0
> 7 warn lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/3527/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
> 8 verbose lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
> 9 verbose lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: PATH: /snap/node/3527/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/jreyes/Projects/mothersrfc/client/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
> 10 verbose lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/jreyes/Projects/mothersrfc/client
> 11 silly lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch' ]
> 12 silly lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
> 13 info lifecycle mothersrfc-client@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
> 14 verbose stack Error: mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start: `webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch`
> 14 verbose stack Exit status 2
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/snap/node/3527/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
> 14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snap/node/3527/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
> 14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> 14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
> 14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
> 15 verbose pkgid mothersrfc-client@1.0.0
> 16 verbose cwd /home/jreyes/Projects/mothersrfc/client
> 17 verbose Linux 5.4.0-59-generic
> 18 verbose argv "/snap/node/3527/bin/node" "/snap/node/3527/bin/npm" "start"
> 19 verbose node v14.15.4
> 20 verbose npm  v6.14.10
> 21 error code ELIFECYCLE
> 22 error errno 2
> 23 error mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start: `webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch`
> 23 error Exit status 2
> 24 error Failed at the mothersrfc-client@1.0.0 start script.
> 24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> 25 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
> ```

---

**Edit:** I'm using `webpack` version `5.11.1` and `webpack-cli` version `4.3.1`

Comment: code your webpack

Comment: information more from webpack https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/

Comment: got it. I setup my webpack.config.js file with the right entry point, and the bundle destination. Now everything works by running my npm script which just calls 'webpack' and I made a watch script that just runs 'webpack --watch' THANK YOU ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

**package.json**

```json
// package.json
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "scripts": {
        //"start": "webpack src/index.js --output bin/app.js -d --watch",
       "build": "webpack --mode=production webpack.config.js",
       "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development webpack.config.js"
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
   entry: path.join(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
   output: {
     filename: "[name].bundle.js",
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers they helped me figure out how to solve it. I made my webpack.config.js and the only thing is I just did in my package.json.... 'build':'webpack' as well as 'watch':'webpack --watch' and it all worked.    I did not have my directories setup correctly either. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

webpack-cli v4 changed how the entry points are parsed.

#### v3

```sh
webpack a.js b.js -o dist
```

#### v4

```sh
webpack --entry a.js --entry b.js -o dist
```